# How to connect a domain name to a virtual host 's sub folder without creating a virtualhost for the new domain name?

Tags: apache-httpd

Suppose you have 2 domain names..

```
 domain1.tld
 domain2.tld
```

your server ip is : 1.1.1.1

you install httpd and set up a virtual host for the IP only.

```
Listen *:80
DirectoryIndex index.php

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /1/
ServerName ooo
</VirtualHost>
```

you have not setup anything for the domains.. 
but because the domais are pointing to your server's ip via DNS

they still come to this VirtualHost on the Web.

i do not use php but let's assume there is a index.php 
in this virtual host.

it wants to know what domain is being used so it can 
go into mysql and display the appropriate content.

how can index.php be aware of what domain is being used ?

or suppose you run a web site like youtube or twitter..
instead of youtube.com/username

you want to be able to offer your users ability to use
their own domain names.

how can you go about connecting a domain name to..

youtube.com/username

?

Comment: The [`SERVER_NAME`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) parameter can be used by PHP. But I really don't see what what the subfolder has to do with domains in `domain.tld/subfolder`.

Comment: Your questions are very hard to understand. Even if English isn't your native language, please make an effort to be understood. Write complete sentences, starting with a capital letter and ending with a full stop. Don't put line breaks in random places.

Answer (score 0):

`php` will be passed environment variables from `apache`.  One of them is an array called [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) which contains information about the server and the request it's currently processing.

One of the elements of `$_SERVER` is `HTTP_HOST` which contains the name of the server as requested by the client (generally the server part of the URL in the browser's address bar).

A `php` script can then use this value to determine which URL was requested and act accordingly.